# How to download two different dataframes in the same file in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a basic shiny app in which I want to download a file with two different dataframes in it (iris, mtcars). Is this possible? I do not care about which one will be displayed first or second.In the vesrion below the file is broken but I add it like this in order to make more clear what I want.

```
### ui.R

library(shiny)
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
  uiOutput("ex") ,
  uiOutput("down")


  ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput('plot')

  )
)
#server.r
function(input, output, session) {
  output$ex<-renderUI({
      radioButtons("extension","File Format", choices = c("txt","csv","tsv","json"))

  })
  output$down<-renderUI({

      #Download files with quotes or not depending on the quote=input$quotes which has value TRUE or FALSE.
      output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste("file", input$extension, sep = ".")
        },

        # This function should write data to a file given to it by
        # the argument 'file'.
        content = function(file) {
          sep <- switch(input$extension,"txt"=",", "csv" = ",", "tsv" = "\t","json"=",")
          # Write to a file specified by the 'file' argument
          write.table(data.frame(iris,mtcars), file, sep = sep,
                      row.names = FALSE) 

        }

      )
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
  })

}
```

Comment: Since the frames are unlikely to be `rbind`-able (incompatible dimensions), you'll need to `write.table(iris,...)` and then `write.table(mtcars, append=TRUE, ...)`.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work. I just get the app title and no functionality

Comment: it works if you delete the mtcars and open it in a browser

Comment: it works with r2evans suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @r2evans rightly pointed out, you can just add `append = TRUE` to all `write.table` following the first call to download multiple dataframes in one file.

**server.r**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ex<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("extension","File Format", choices = c("txt","csv","tsv","json"))

  })
  output$down<-renderUI({
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

      #FileName
      filename = function() {
        paste("file", input$extension, sep = ".")
      },

      # This function should write data to a file given to it by
      # the argument 'file'.
      content = function(file) {
        sep <- switch(input$extension,"txt"=",", "csv" = ",", "tsv" = "\t","json"=",")

        write.table(iris, file, sep = sep, row.names = FALSE)
        write.table(mtcars, file, sep = sep, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)       

      }

    )
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
  })

}
```